# Función estatica helper en Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend

tengo un módulo en ZendFramework que quiero utilizarlo como helper, con diferentes funcionalidades que reutilizo en otros lugares del código.

Llevo poco tiempo en esta materia y tengo dificultades, por lo que les solicito su ayuda.

En primer lugar, les muestro mi directorio de trabajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase helper con las funciones reutilizables se denomina Utility.php, y quiero utilizar en map.phtml.
Su contenido es muy simple:

```
<?php

namespace src\BlockEditor;
class Utility{

  public static  function intoCss($a){

        return $a->unit;
    
    }
}

 ?>
```

Por último, la utilizo de esta forma en archivo map.phtml, con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php
use src\BlockEditor;
?>
    <div style="width: 100%, margin:<?php Utility::intoCss('')?>"><iframe scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps></iframe></div>
```

Me da error, y no encuentro el motivo. Gracias.

Comment: Hola. 1. ¿Qué versión de zendframework usas (hay muchas diferencias de fondo e incompatibilidades entre 1x, 2x y 3x? 2. Esto no se ajusta al modelo de espacios de nombres: `namespace src\BlockEditor;` debiera estar calificado de la forma `nombre_modulo\BlockEditor` de modo que no creo que Utility esté cargada en el momento en que la invocas. 3. No te puedo aclarar más porque hay cambios ostensibles en las estructuras de directorios entre versiones y tu imagen no muestra si src está bajo Application, bajo un módulo tuyo o en otra parte.

Comment: Adicionalmente. Trata de entrar a las páginas de documentación de ZF. Notarás que ahora se llama **[Laminas](https://getlaminas.org/)** y se anuncia como continuación de zend ¡sabrá dios en que dirección! ...

Comment: Solucionado, Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía que mencionar el nombre del modulo en el espacio de nombres, Utilizo ZF3, y la llamada a la clase utility la he puesto totalmente cualificado, y ha funcionado a la perfección.

Gracias!

Comment: Sería bueno que muestres los detalles de la solución. De seguro la van a resultar de utilidad a otros usuarios de ZF. Particularmente a los que no hayan profundizado en como se declara un **namespace** en ese framework para que se ajuste al mecanismo de autocarga.